# Exclude some paths from :find path

Tags: find

I'm working on a large scale project with a lot of files, and `:find` is extremely (several seconds) slow, much slower than `:lgrep` backed by `ag`, which skips directories mentioned in `.gitignore`, e.g. `tmp`, `log`, `node_modules` etc.

At the moment I'm using `set path=.,**`.

Is there a way exclude specific paths from `path`?

Any trick with `autocmd` loading `.gitignore` and setting `path` on  `VimEnter` will work.

Answer (score 3):

`vim-rails` and `vim-ruby` are setting `path`, and they don't really care that `path` is limited to 1024 characters on some platforms throwing out what you set.

Solved with `autocmd`:

```
let g:project_find_path = '.,' . system("git ls-tree -d HEAD --name-only | tr '\n' : | sed 's/:/**,/g'")
autocmd VimEnter let &path = g:project_find_path
autocmd BufReadPost * let &path = g:project_find_path
```

Works in fractions of a second now.